# Merge open graph app with existing page

Tags: facebook, facebook-like, facebook-opengraph

Been fixing some issues with our "Like"-buttons on several sites, since apparently you need to post them via an Open Graph application since Nov. 7th?

One of the requirements so it seems is to create a page for your application, but we've already had a Facebook page for our blog. Is there anyway I can merge them? I see no use for keeping a separate  App Page next to our default page?